# req.body is undefined in express 4.13.1

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, body-parser

i have a problem and i don't know the problem. Please, help me to find the solution.

In the Angular view i have:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
<input ng-model="stickie_text" type="text" id="sticky_content" />
<button type="submit" id="add_sticky" value="add a new stickie!">new sticky</button>
```

In the client side (AngularJS) i have this controller:

```
dcuApp.controller('rankingController', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http) {$scope.submit = function(){
// console.log("holaaaa");
console.log($scope.stickie_text);
$http.get('/api/get-ranking',{"valor":$scope.stickie_text}).then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
        console.log("RANKING: "+$scope.data);
    },
    function(response) {
        console.debug('Error:' + response);
    });
 };
 }]);
```

In the server side (Express 4.13.1) i have:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = require('../model/db');
var model = require('../model/model');
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); //used to manipulate POST

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
router.use(methodOverride(function(req, res){
      if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
        // look in urlencoded POST bodies and delete it
        var method = req.body._method
        delete req.body._method
        return method
      }
}));

router.get('/api/get-ranking',function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.body.valor);
});
```

The problem is that req.body.valor is UNDEFINED.

I know there are other postings that relate to this problem, but have not managed to fix it.

Please, I need help to get on the server side, a different req.body.valor to undefined

thanks!!! :)

Comment: You're doing a GET request ?

Comment: @adeneo is correct, you should convert request to `post` on server side as well as on client side.. otherwise parameter will get added inside URL as query parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a `GET` request and send `data` along with it. You need to use `POST` request to achieve what you want. You cannot send data in a `GET` request.

You need to change your current `GET` method to `POST`.

**Replace :**

```
router.get('/api/get-ranking',function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.body.valor);
});
```

**with**

```
router.post('/api/get-ranking',function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.body.valor);
});
```

also,

**Replace :**

```
$http.get('/api/get-ranking',{"valor":$scope.stickie_text})
```

**with:**

```
$http.post('/api/get-ranking',{"valor":$scope.stickie_text})
```

Hope this helps.